# How to clear the (Master) sign from git bash?

Tags: bash, git

I  have a Windows PC with git installed. Whenever I start git bash, it always stands at /c/Users/_user with the master branch as below:  `user@DESKTOP-VE8378L MINGW64 ~ (master)`
I guess it should look like `user@DESKTOP-VE8378L MINGW64 ~`

I had a look at people around, found out that they don't have `(master)` at their first start using git bash. I checked `git repo` at where I stand with `git remote -v` but there is nothing.

I tried `git status` but there is also nothing to help.

Comment: Switch to another branch and the name of that branch will appear instead of master.

Comment: You need to change the value of the `PS1` variable; how to do that is a better question for unix.stackexchange.com or superuser.com.

Comment: Run `git rev-parse --show-toplevel`, it will print the directory where you seem to have accidentally created a repository.

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO. Please, post the output of all the commands you executed.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you created a git repository in your home directory?
Do you have a .git directory in your home?
If that's the case you should move that repository in a different directory, or delete the .git direcotory if it was created by mistake.

Comment: This is a valid and useful _comment_ but it's not an answer.

Comment: It is indeed an answer. The description of the problem is suggesting exactly this behavior, the answer is probably valid as well. That one is a git repository, to "purge" the "(master)", one should remove the git repository from the folder.

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO. Please, rephrase your answer as an answer, and post your questions (if any) as comments under the original post.